# Database theory: best way to have a "flags" table which could apply to many entities?

Tags: database, data-modeling, theory

I'm building a data model for a new project I'm developing. Part of this data model involves entities having "flags".

A flag is simply a boolean value - either an entity has the flag or it does not have the flag. To that end I have a table simply called "flags" that has an ID, a string name, and a description.  (An example of a flag might be "is active" or "should be displayed" or "belongs to group".)

So for example, any user in my users table could have none, one, or many flags. So I create a userFlags bridge table with user ID and flag ID. If the table contains a row for the given flag ID and user ID, that user has that flag.

Ok, so now I add another entity - say "section". Each section can also have flags. So I create a sectionFlags table to accommodate this.

Now I have another entity - "content", so again, "contentFlags".

And so on.

My final data model has basically two tables per entity, one to hold the entity and one for flags.

While this certainly *works*, it seems like there may be a better way to design my model, so I don't have to have so many bridge tables. One idea I had was a master "hasFlags" table with flag ID, item ID and item type. The item type could be an enumerated field only accepting values corresponding to known entities. The only problem there is that my foreign key for the entity will not work because each "item ID" could refer to a different entity. (I have actually used this technique in other data models, and while it certainly works, you lose referential integrity as well as things like cascade updates.)

Or, perhaps my data model is fine as-is and that's just the nature of the beast.

Any more-advanced experienced DB devs care to chime in?

Answer (score 1):

The many-to-many relationships are one way to do it (and possibly faster than what I'm about to suggest because they can use integer key indexes).

The other way to do this is with a polymorphic relationship.

Your entity-to-flag table needs 2 columns as well as the foreign key link to the flag table;

```
other_key integer not null
other_type varchar(...) not null
```

And in those fields you store the foreign key of the relation in the integer and the type of the relation in the varchar. Full-on ORMs that support this sometimes store the class name of the foreign relation in the type column, to aid with object loading.

The downside here is that the integer can't be a true foreign key as it will contain duplicates from many tables. It also makes your querying a bit more interesting per-join than the many-to-many tables, but it does allow you to generalise your join in code.